# java 1.6 maven checkstyle eclipse

Tags: maven, checkstyle, java-6

Is there a way to make this work? It seems my project always downloads the 3.5.1 version of maven-site-plugin and since Im stuck on java 1.6 its not working.
In my pom I have

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.15</version>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<reporting>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.15</version>
          <reportSets>
            <reportSet>
              <reports>
                <report>checkstyle</report>
              </reports>
            </reportSet>
          </reportSets>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Comment: Since you are using Java 6, have you tried incorporating https://github.com/rnveach/checkstyle-backport-jre6 with checkstyle maven?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use some quite ancient versions, but it is possible. Refer to the [Checkstyle Compatibility Matrix](https://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html?hl=6.1.1[g]) to see the versions.

Mostly, you will have to use Checkstyle 6.1.1, and [configure your Maven to use it](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html), too.